# Can we have spark-jobserver in windows?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Is it possible to run spark-jobserver in windows without using any emulator like cygwin ? I have tried gitbash as well, as I thought it supports .sh files but I didn't get any luck.

Note : I have tried building the source code of spark-jobserver from github but still no luck.

Comment: Can you add more information in the question? Like which command are you running for building and what is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: have you fond the solution yet?